# Need to Fetch Row which have count 2

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table A such as 
       TABLE1

```
  =======================
  | id | product_id | filter_id | category_id |
  | 16 | 33         | 6         | Null        |
  | 23 | 40         | 16        | 76          |
  | 48 | 20         | 6         | 45          |
  | 69 | 10         | 6         | 87          |
  | 70 | 10         | 9         | 67          |
```

Now i have to find product_id 10 which have filter_id 6 and 9

Comment: Please always provide what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use [`having`](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/having.php)

```
select 
    product_id, count(product_id) 
from 
    teble1 
group by
    product_id
having
    count(product_id) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

use one of this samples

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE products_id = 10
AND filter_id IN (6,9);
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE products_id = 10
AND (filter_id = 6 OR filter_id = 9);
```

Comment: IMO I think OP want to find row have `count(product_id) = 2`, as in title of OP's question

Comment: @Pham X. Bach - yes you right - take the answer from Pham X. Bach